# Why did the FvD board opt for suspending former leader Baudet, rather than letting him run in a board approved leadership election?

Tags: parties, netherlands, political-leaders

Over the past few days, the Dutch party Forum voor Democratie (FvD) has been in the news a lot. [Thierry Baudet's Dutch Wikipedia page](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thierry_Baudet) describes the events of the past few days as follows:

> Op 23 november 2020 gaf Baudet aan niet langer meer te willen fungeren als lijsttrekker voor FvD bij de komende Tweede Kamerverkiezingen in 2021 en stelde het partijleiderschap ter beschikking. Hij gaf aan wel in de Tweede Kamer te blijven tot aan de verkiezingen. Eventueel wilde hij nog wel lijstduwer worden bij de Tweede Kamerverkiezingen. Op 25 november 2020 kwam Baudet terug op zijn voornemen geen lijsttrekker voor FvD meer te willen zijn. Hij wil zich verkiesbaar stellen voor het lijsttrekkerschap en riep lijsttrekkersverkiezingen uit, zonder medeweten van het partijbestuur, die de verkiezingen daarop illegitiem noemde daar ze niet berusten op een bestuursbesluit en eiste het vertrek van Baudet.

Translated by me:

> On 23 November 2020, Baudet indicated that he longer wanted to act as lead candidate [or *list puller*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijsttrekker) for FvD for the Dutch parliamentary election in 2021. He resigned as party leader. He indicated that he will complete his term in parliament. Possibly, he wanted to act as [*list pusher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijstduwer) for the 2021 parliamentary election.
>
> On 25 November 2020, Baudet retracted his intention to not be the lead candidate for FvD. He wants to run for lead candidate and called an election, without consulting the party board. The party board then called the election for lead candidate illegitimate because it's not based on a board decision. The board then called for Baudet to leave the party.

[Calling for Baudet's suspension from the party](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://nos.nl/artikel/2358034-chaos-bij-forum-baudet-zet-leiderschapsverkiezing-door-meerderheid-bestuur-wil-hem-royeren.html) seems odd to me because Baudet resigned the leadership of his own will. While he may not be in a position to call a leadership election, suspending seems like an overreaction.

I wonder if the board (or individual board members) has explained why they opt for suspension, rather than letting Baudet run in an election that they do approve of. After all, it seems that the party needs a leader for the next election.